# MongoDB accessing query for date is not working

Tags: java, mongodb, time

I am storing following object in menus collection. Then I make following query and it doesn't find any records. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
>> Menu.java
    private String menuId;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

>> Store.java
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(collectionType);
    String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(object);
    DBObject dbObj = (DBObject) JSON.parse(jsonString);
    collection.save(dbObj);

>> String generated is
{"menuId":"1","startDate":"Jul 12, 2013 8:52:48 AM","endDate":"Jul 22, 2013 8:52:48 AM"}

>> Query defined for startDate < currentdate < endDate
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("startDate", new BasicDBObject("$lte", AbstractJson.getDate(days))).append("endDate", new BasicDBObject("$gte", AbstractJson.getDate(days)));

{ "startDate" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2013-07-17T13:02:56.697Z"}} , "endDate" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2013-07-17T13:02:58.510Z"}}}
```

Comment: Seems that `startDate` and `endDate` fields are not been stored as date type. Check your GSON parser and the MongoDB docs about [date/time in java](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/#dates-times) to store dates properly.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. Now we decided to store time in long value.
So now it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Miguel. Now we decided to store time in long value. So now it is ok.